# How to update a user's Facebook status?

Tags: php, facebook

I looked at many similar questions here at Stackoverflow.com and searched in Google but still could not find an answer, so I am posting this new question.

I have a 3rd party PHP5 website in which users can write a short message. I want to have the ability for the user to click a button to share that message as a facebook status.
It is in my understanding that this can be done using the Facebook API and [Users.setStatus](http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Users.setStatus). I am not sure where to begin though - do I implement Facebook connect in my site? I don't need anything but that ability, so I don't need a facebook 'canvas' page.
Do I start an application?
Could someone point me in the right direction?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to:

1. [Create an application](http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Creating_a_Platform_Application), paying particular attention to the Connect settings
2. Integrate your site with [Facebook
   Connect](http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Facebook_Connect)
3. Check the user has granted the
   application the [`status_update`
   extended permission](http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Extended_permission), and if not
   pop up the [permission dialogue](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/?u=facebook.jslib.FB.Connect.showPermissionDialog)
4. Use the [`Status.set` API call](http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Status.set)

The details for each step are far too big for one SO answer, but hopefully that's a "point in the right direction".

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to create a facebook application in order to set someone's status with `Users.setStatus`. You should keep in mind that users will have to install your application and allow it to publish on their behalf before you can do so, though.

Check out [developer.facebook.com](http://developer.facebook.com/) to get started.